# XML string Vs. Object which one is good for performance

Tags: c#, .net, xml, object

In one of my project communication between application, business and data layer is performed in xml format, but I feel it is a time consuming way and communication should happen in object form only as all layers are in same .net technology. If I am right in the way I thinking and how much performance improvement I can get from this.

Ex. 
1)

Through XML String :-

```
StringBuilder strReq = new StringBuilder();
strReq.AppendFormat("<Request>");
strReq.AppendFormat("<RequestID>{0}</RequestID>", RequestID);
strReq.AppendFormat("<CType>{0}</CType>", CType);
strReq.AppendFormat("<ID>{0}</ID>", 0);
strReq.AppendFormat("<Source>{0}</Source>", Source);
strReq.AppendFormat("<VirtualNo>{0}</VirtualNo>", VirtualNo);
```

Through Object :-

```
clsRequest objRequest = new clsRequest ()
objRequest.RequestId = RequestId;
objRequest.CType= CType
```

etc..................

Comment: I would *reject* the first code snippet in a code-review. Go with the 97/3 rule, and don't make up problems that don't exist. If you don't wish to use POCO-wrapper objects (e.g. XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer), at least consider using a proper XML generator like [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx) or the DOM.

Comment: What happens if any of these variables, ie `Source` contains reserved characters like '<' and '>'?

Comment: In this application only few selected special characters are allowed and '<' or '>' is not of them

Comment: Yikes; `clsRequest`, `strReq` and `objRequest`. You realise my day is basically shot down after reading those names, right? ;p More seriously, every naming recommendation / guideline / automated code-review for about the last decade has been: "don't do that"

Comment: I guess it's one of those applications like the UK tax return where the user is told he can't use "&" and "<" in text fields. Yuk. Programmers who make the user suffer because they are lazy should be shot.

Answer (score 2):

There's only one way to objectively measure the performance difference between implementation A and implementation B, and that is to measure both. But if you aren't crossing any process / app-domain boundaries, I have to agree that it is entirely pointless pushing it down to xml - that involves lots of overhead. It would seem entirely correct and appropriate to just pass it down as a `Request` instance, or something more specific - `BananaRequest`, etc.

Also, your current code (as already noted in comments) is simply broken - it is not a reliable or robust serialization approach.